# Awk/sed command to print pattern1 only if patterm 2 macthes

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, command-line

Trying to get the "Log" line printed only if "ref1" is present in the text following the "Log" line

sample text :

```
Log 0102
............
.....ref1.......
......ref1....
Log 0103
............
.....ref1.......
....
Log 0104
............
.....ref2.......
......
```

expected result :

```
Log 0102
Log 0103
```

result i am getting:

```
Log 0102
Log 0102
Log 0103
```

i tried this awk command but not getting results:

```
awk '/Log*/ line =$0}/ref1/{print line}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
/^Log/{
  if(found){ print value }
  value=$0
  found=""
  next
}
/ref1/{
  found=1
}
END{
  if(found){
     print value
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***OR*** a one-liner form of above code.

`awk awk '/^Log/{if(found){print value};value=$0;found="";next} /ref1/{found=1} END{if(found){print value}}'  Input_file`

Comment: It is only printing the first "Log" line not the second occurence :/

Comment: @MUSKANGURJAR, with your shown samples it printed both lines 102 and 103 lines for me. Is your actual file same as shown samples?

Comment: @MUSKANGURJAR, Your previous comment is removed. This code is working and is given as per shown samples. Not sure on your shell script may be some other issue is there with it. Request you to kindly open a new question for same with proper code and details like this one and we can discuss it there, cheers.

Comment: If i add "ref1" to the block below "Log0104" then it doesn't include it, it's printing only "Log 0102 Log 0103"

Comment: @MUSKANGURJAR, Ok I have added edited solution, please do check it and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: It worked ! Thsnkyou so much !

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu-awk` this is fairly simple with custom `RS`:

```bash
awk -v RS='(^|\n)Log ' '/ref1/ {printf "Log %s\n", $1}' file

Log 0102
Log 0103
```

Here `-v RS='(^|\n)Log '` sets `RS` to `Log` followed by a space. `Log` should be preceded by start position or a line break.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> mawk 'gsub("^|Log [^\n]+|"FS,"\1&\2",$!(NF-=+_<NF)) + \
>       gsub("\2[^\1\2]*\1","\n") + \
>       gsub("^[\1\2]+|[\1\2]\n[^\1\2]+$",_)^_' RS= FS='ref1'
> ```

```
Log 0102
Log 0103
```